# Vagrant で nfs を使った synced_folder が機能しない

Tags: vagrant

Vagrant で CoreOS を立ち上げようとしています。
その際に NFS を使って synced_folder で同期をしたいんですが、 `vagrant up` をしても途中で処理が止まってしまい正常に立ち上げられません。
色々と調べても原因が分からないためお知恵をお借りしたいです。

CoreOS は以下のリポジトリのものを使用しています。
https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant

手を加えた箇所は README に書いてあるように Vagrantfile の95行目をアンコメントしているのみです。
`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/core/share", id: "core", :nfs => true, :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp']`

実際に `vagrant up` をした時に吐き出されるメッセージが以下になります。

```
Bringing machine 'core-01' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> core-01: Importing base box 'coreos-alpha'...
==> core-01: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> core-01: Checking if box 'coreos-alpha' is up to date...
==> core-01: Setting the name of the VM: coreos-vagrant_core-01_1421312749866_77635
==> core-01: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> core-01: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    core-01: Adapter 1: nat
    core-01: Adapter 2: hostonly
    core-01: Adapter 3: hostonly
==> core-01: Forwarding ports...
    core-01: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> core-01: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> core-01: Booting VM...
==> core-01: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    core-01: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    core-01: SSH username: core
    core-01: SSH auth method: private key
    core-01: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> core-01: Machine booted and ready!
==> core-01: Setting hostname...
==> core-01: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> core-01: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> core-01: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
Password:
==> core-01: Mounting NFS shared folders...
```

`Mounting NFS shared folders` と表示されたまま何も出力されず反応がなくなってしまいます。
NFS サービスはちゃんと動いていることが確認出来ています。

```
$ nfsd status
nfsd service is enabled
nfsd is running (pid 21562, 8 threads)
```

エラーメッセージも見つけられず行き詰っています。
よろしくお願いします。

*追記(2015.01.16)*
/etc/exports の中身がどうなっているか質問がありましたので下記に記載します。

```
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 cf7c54a8-1366-4d3b-9c99-0a1d15996f1f
"/path/to/coreos-vagrant" 172.17.8.101 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
# VAGRANT-END: 501 cf7c54a8-1366-4d3b-9c99-0a1d15996f1f
```

Comment: よろしければ /etc/exports の内容を追記していただけますか？

Comment: 返事が遅くなってすみません。
/etc/exports の中身について質問文へ追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらで [Running \`vagrant up` hangs on NFS mounting (Vagrant 1.4.3)](https://github.com/wunki/vagrant-freebsd/issues/4) 同じ問題が取り上げられています。解決に繋がるかどうかは分かりませんが、ご参考までにどうぞ。

Comment: 英語圏のものも探してはいたんですがこの issue は初めて見ました。観測不足ですね、ありがとうございます。
しかしながら、issue で挙がっている方法を試しても変わらずといった結果になりました…
もう少し試行錯誤してみようと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ホスト側のファイアウォールの問題では？、と想像します。

( `nfsd status` なので、勝手に OS X と想定して、、)
とりあえず、`システム環境設定` の `セキュリティとプライバシー` の `ファイアウォール` タブで、 `ファイアウォールを切にする` で試してみて、
これで動きだすなら、たぶんキャッシュが飛んだような気がするので、再び入にしても大丈夫な気がします。(必要に応じて、適切な設定に戻してくださいませ。。)

### 追記

単純に nfs でマウントするのはどうでしょう？

1. `Vagrantfile` の `config.vm.synced_folder` をコメントアウトに戻して `$ vagrant up` します。
2. ターミナルで `ifconfig vboxnet0` などを実行して、ホスト側の ip address を確認します。(例では **172.17.8.1** )

   ```
   $ ifconfig vboxnet0
   vboxnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
           ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
           inet 172.17.8.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.17.8.255
   ```
3. `vagrant ssh` で CoreOS に入ります。
4. `ip a show dev eth1` で ip address を確認します。(例では **172.17.8.101** )

   ```
   core@core-01 ~ $ ip a show dev eth1
   3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP qlen 1000
       link/ether 08:00:27:a2:ed:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
       inet 172.17.8.101/24 brd 172.17.8.255 scope global eth1
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fea2:edd8/64 scope link 
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   core@core-01 ~ $
   ```
5. 一旦 `exit` して(もしくはもう一枚ターミナルを開いて)、 `/etc/exports` に CoreOS の ip address に許可を出していることを確認します。( 違う値になっているなら修正します)

   ```
   $ cat /etc/exports
   # VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 cf7c54a8-1366-4d3b-9c99-0a1d15996f1f
   "/path/to/coreos-vagrant" 172.17.8.101 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
   # VAGRANT-END: 501 cf7c54a8-1366-4d3b-9c99-0a1d15996f1f
   $
   ```
6. CoreOS 側に入って、ホスト側に `ping` が通るか確認しつつ、素手でマウンントしてみます。(nolock だけは必須っぽいです)

   ```
   core@core-01 ~ $ ping -c 3 172.17.8.1
   PING 172.17.8.1 (172.17.8.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from 172.17.8.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.362 ms
   64 bytes from 172.17.8.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.410 ms
   64 bytes from 172.17.8.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.552 ms

   --- 172.17.8.1 ping statistics ---
   3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.362/0.441/0.552/0.082 ms
   core@core-01 ~ $ 
   core@core-01 ~ $ 
   core@core-01 ~ $ mkdir mount_point
   core@core-01 ~ $ sudo mount -t nfs -o "nolock" 172.17.8.1:/path/to/coreos-vagrant ./mount_point
   core@core-01 ~ $ ls mount_point/
   README.md  Vagrantfile  config.rb  config.rb.sample  user-data  user-data.sample
   core@core-01 ~ $
   ```

(後からこの問題を参照する人向けに、以下はコメントからのフィードバックしています。)

7. ping が通らない場合は VirtualBox で vboxnet0 の設定を消去して再度 CoreOS を立ち上げ直してから試すと正常にもどるようです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
仰るとおりホストには OS X を使用しています。
ファイアウォールの設定を無効して試してみましたが現象は変わらないようでした…困りました

Comment: ざんねんです。。素手で mount する方法を追記してみました。(既に試しているのであれば、スルーしてください。。)

Comment: 度々ありがとうございます。記載された手順で動作を試してみたところ、ゲストからホストに ping を打つところでつまずきました。timeout して反応がありませんでした。  
ですので念のため、 VirtualBox で vboxnet0 の設定を消去して再度 CoreOS を立ち上げ → ping をしてみたところ今度は問題なく通りました。そしてその後の手動 mount もすんなり出来ました。これはもしやと思い、もう一度最初から Vagrant up で立ち上げてみたら無事 NFS でマウントしました！
結局、根本の原因はよく分からずでしたがうまく同期出来て助かりました。ありがとうございました！