# vagrantのsynced_folderの設定をnfsにした時にtimeoutしてしまう

Tags: vagrant

## 事象

Vagrantのsynced_folderをnfsで行おうとしております。
ただ、nfsの設定をsynced_folderのオプションに追加し、vagrant upをすると、マウントの部分で処理が止まっているようで、先に進めなくなってしまっております。

vagrant up --debugでの出力メッセージが下記になります。

```
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: mount -o 'rw,vers=3,tcp,fsc,actimeo=2' 192.168.33.1:'/Path/Sync' /vagrant (sudo=true)
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: stderr: mount.nfs: Connection timed out

DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 32
 INFO retryable: Retryable exception raised: #<Vagrant::Errors::LinuxNFSMountFailed: The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o 'rw,vers=3,tcp,fsc,actimeo=2' 192.168.33.1:'/Path/Sync' /vagrant

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

Vagrantfileは下記のようにしています。

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos6.7"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/CommanderK5/packer-centos-template/releases/download/0.6.7/vagrant-centos-6.7.box"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3307
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000

  config.vm.synced_folder './', '/vagrant', id: "vagrant", :nfs => true, :mount_options => ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp', 'fsc', 'actimeo=2']
  # config.vm.synced_folder './', '/vagrant'
end
```

## 環境

Host : Mac OSX 10.11.6
guest : CentOS 6.7

## 試したこと１

[Vagrant で nfs を使った synced_folder が機能しない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/4604/vagrant-%E3%81%A7-nfs-%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F-synced-folder-%E3%81%8C%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
こちらの投稿が、おそらく同じ事象であると思われるのですが、下記のいずれも解決が出来ませんでした。

- ホストPCのファイアーウォールの設定をOFFにする
- Vagrantfile の config.vm.synced_folderのコメントアウトして、手動でnfsしてみる
  → 上記の投稿の回答欄にある、ゲスト側からホスト側にpingが通っているところまでは確認出来ました。
  　ただ、`sudo mount -t nfs -o "nolock"...`をすると、ここでも応答が返ってこない状態でした。

## 試したこと２

http://qiita.com/metheglin/items/ba6865c436e6948f27b5
こちらの記事もマウントがうまく行っていない事象のようでしたので、こちらに記載されている、`/etc/hosts`や、`/etc/exports`の設定変更も試してみましたが、やはり結果は同じく`mount.nfs: Connection timed out`になってしまいました。

nfsを使わなければ、sync自体は出来ているので、良いのですが、nfsの方がパフォーマンスが良いとの事でしたので、出来れば設定したく思っております。

どなかた、お知恵を拝借出来ますと幸いでございます。
何卒、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちら自己解決が出来ました。
原因は、macに入れていたウィルスソフトの方のファイアーウォールの設定でした。
`192.168.33.0/24`のゾーンを許可する事で、無事にマウントをさせる事が出来ました。

参考サイト
https://github.com/wunki/vagrant-freebsd/issues/4